# __TIMESTAMP__ has wrong Date / Time in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, unix-timestamp

Im using the `__TIMESTAMP__` literal in my C++ program. But when I comile my program, the **TIMESTAMP** var holds the wrong date and time. It doesn't match my pc's date and time.
I wanted to use the var as a build stamp...
The porgram runs on an embedded linux system..

Comment: What values does it hold? What is the expected value and what is the actual value?

Comment: The variable is now "Fri Feb 26 10:57:23 2016" on compilation time. Compilation time of the host PC is now (02.03.2016, 12:57).

Comment: So am I the only one with this problem?

Comment: So nobody?? No Ideas??